# How to draw Angle in between two lines in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

i have four divs that is p1,p2,p3,p4. it is draggable. at any point i click "draw" button iwant to draw angle sign like below

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var c=document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(parseInt($("#p1").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p1").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt($("#p2").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p2").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt($("#p3").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p3").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt($("#p4").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p4").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt($("#p1").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p1").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.fillStyle='#E6E0EC';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle="#604A7B";
    ctx.lineWidth="3"
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    $("#p1,#p2,#p3,#p4").draggable({
    drag:function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(parseInt($("#p1").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p1").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt($("#p2").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p2").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt($("#p3").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p3").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt($("#p4").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p4").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.lineTo(parseInt($("#p1").css("left"))-5,parseInt($("#p1").css("top"))-5)
    ctx.fillStyle='#E6E0EC';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle="#604A7B";
    ctx.lineWidth="3"
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
                   }

    });
```

How can i make this please provide simple solution.

the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/b954W/

[image]

[image]

i want to draw the arc inside the shape at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to illustrate the angle between line segments**

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/XnL3B/

[image]

**Step#1: Calculate the angles**

You can calculate the angle between 2 lines connected at a vertex using Math.atan2:

```
// calculate the angles in radians using Math.atan2

var dx1=pt1.x-pt2.x;
var dy1=pt1.y-pt2.y;
var dx2=pt3.x-pt2.x;
var dy2=pt3.y-pt2.y;
var a1=Math.atan2(dy1,dx1);
var a2=Math.atan2(dy2,dx2);
```

**Step#2: Draw the angle's wedge**

You can draw the wedge illustrating the angle using context.arc:

```
// draw angleSymbol using context.arc

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(pt2.x,pt2.y);
ctx.arc(pt2.x,pt2.y,20,a1,a2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.globalAlpha=0.25;
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
```

**Step#3: Draw the degree angle in text**

And you can draw the text of the angle (converted to degrees) using context.fillText:

```
// draw the degree angle in text

var a=parseInt((a2-a1)*180/Math.PI+360)%360;
ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.fillText(a,pt2.x+15,pt2.y);
```

Comment: it works well but any point i want to draw the arc inside the shape not outside. pls help me.

Comment: please refer above image